# Find domain of the function $f(x) =\sqrt{\log_{\sin x +\cos x}|\cos x| +\cos x}$ in $[0,\pi]$

Tags: functions, solution-verification

I just need a solution verification, because I thought the answer I got was too odd

For $\cos x > 0$

$$\cos x + \cos x \ge 1$$

$$\cos x \ge \frac 12$$

$$x\in [0,\frac{\pi}{3}]$$

$\cos x <0$ can be ignored because it won’t satisfy

$$\sin x +\cos x > 1$$

$$\sin (x+\frac{\pi}{4})> \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$

$$x+\frac{\pi}{4}>\frac{\pi}{4} \text {or} \frac{3\pi}{4}$$

$$x>0$$

Then $$x\in (0,\frac{\pi}{3})$$

Again, I don’t think I got this right. It seems very loose and has a lot of missing parts. Please let me know what I did wrong.

Comment: Why do you have $\sin x+ \cos x \color{red}{\geq}1$, shouldn't it be $\sin x+ \cos x \neq 1$ and $>0$.

Comment: @AnuragA it was a typo

Comment: I think you missed my point: base can be positive and less than $1$, e.g. $\log_{1/2}(1/2)=1$.

Comment: @AnuragA yeah I get that, but it’s more of an either or situation. But is everything I have done right?